# Match multiple instances of pattern in parenthesis

Tags: python-3.x, regex

For the following string, is it possible for regex to return the comma delimited matches within the square brackets?

```
"root.path.definition[id=1234,test=blah,scope=A,B,C,D]"
```

Expected output would be:

```
["id=1234", "test=blah", "scope=A,B,C,D"]
```

The closest I have gotten so far is the following:

```
(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])
```

But this will only return one match for everything within the square brackets.

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: python3 using re module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the re module and first get the part between the square brackets using a capturing group and a negated character class.

```
\[([^][]*)]
```

That part will match:

- `\[` Match `[` char
- `([^][]*)` Capture group 1, match 0+ times any char other than `[` and `]`
- `]` A `[` char

Then get the separate parts by matching the key value pairs separated by a comma.

```
\w+=.*?(?=,\w+=|$)
```

That part will match:

- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `=` Match literally
- `.*?(?=,\w+=|$)` Match as least as possible chars until you either encounter a comma, 1+ word characters and `=` or the end of the string

For example

```
import re

s = "root.path.definition[id=1234,test=blah,scope=A,B,C,D]"

m = re.search(r"\[([^][]*)]", s)
if m:
    print(re.findall(r"\w+=.*?(?=,\w+=|$)", m.group(1)))
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/fjm3xW)

**Output**

```
['id=1234', 'test=blah', 'scope=A,B,C,D']
```

---

If you can make use of the [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), this might also be an option matching the keys and values using lookarounds to assert the `[` and `]`

```
(?<=\[[^][]*)\w+=.*?(?=,\w+=|])(?=[^][]*])
```

For example

```
import regex

s = "root.path.definition[id=1234,test=blah,scope=A,B,C,D]"

print(regex.findall(r"(?<=\[[^][]*)\w+=.*?(?=,\w+=|])(?=[^][]*])", s))
```

**Output**

```
['id=1234', 'test=blah', 'scope=A,B,C,D']
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7UNcGN/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##JYzLCgIhFED3foW40roINS27DD3@wjGYGmuESUUvVNC/21S7A4dz0ovGGJpa/T3FTDy7m3syVjhykWMknXoa9eCuPnjyMRg/4GrdbIBcITxP/QjlEpPDHezhAEcrGEvZB5K/k567oZ8mmYVst9gZc7LGLlT3WKJetLJF@OLbqhn/zioBvChV6wc)

Comment: @paultop6 I have updated the answer and an explanation about the patterns.